# Whitelisting valid URL patterns on a NGINX webserver

Tags: nginx, security, regex, whitelist, url-routing

I want to whitelist only valid URL-patterns on our RESTful webserver / API, using regexs or something. But when googling for some examples I get a little bit suspicious since there is not much documentation on that.

Is it uncommon to do this?

Seems to me it is a very essential part of any webserver script.

What am I overlooking here? :)

Comment: How many valid URLS are you going to have to accept, how many variable things are going to be in them, how long do you think this will take.. and will it really increase security (what if you miss something)?  Also, most importantly what happens if your API changes..

Comment: Yes, it can be maintenance hell :) But seems to me if security is very important, it is a must have.

Comment: But why is it never done? Just because of maintenance issues?

Comment: It might be that people do it, but don't share examples, maybe for security through obscurity?

Comment: What behaviour are you looking for when an invalid URL is hit?

Comment: When an invalid URL is hit, the server just needs to return a 404. Maybe if the error is in the argument of the URL a 400.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't providing any example of where you're falling short in your exercise, or what's the whole purpose of your supposed whitelisting.

How many URLs do you have?  Static web-site, or dynamic?  What are you trying to accomplish?

You could easily do the whitelisting through a set of several specific `location` directives, and then `return 404;` within a general catch-all `location /` (which would match all other locations not described otherwise).

Comment: It is for security purposes. I am wondering why this apparently not common practice. Our current solution is using locations indeed, using regex's. Also there is a performance gain not having to instantiate the application server, only to have it report the error.